# Sending Ctrl+C to console application

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm using the code below to send commands to a console application and receive its output in a string.

Everything works well except the console application doesn't have a command to close or exit. Only by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop/close (finish the job and close properly). I'm stuck here how I can send that key events to the console.

This is the code inside a thread.

```
  procedure DoWork.Execute;
    const
      MAX_CHUNK: dword = 4096;
    var
      Buffer: array [0..MaxBufferSize] of byte;
      SecurityAttributes: SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
      hiRead, hoRead, hiWrite, hoWrite: THandle;
      StartupInfo: TSTARTUPINFO;

      BytesRead, BytesWritten, ExitCode, PipeMode: dword;
      ComSpec:array [0..MAX_PATH] of char;
      ToSend, Tempstr,WorkDir,cmd2,fsize: string;
      i,acc: integer;
      c: cardinal;

    begin

   cmd2 := 'rtmpdump.exe --live -v -r "rtmp://"' ;

      WorkDir :=   'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\rtmpdump';

      SecurityAttributes.nLength := SizeOf(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
      SecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
      SecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle := True;
      CreatePipe(hiRead, hiWrite, @SecurityAttributes, 0);
      CreatePipe(hoRead, hoWrite, @SecurityAttributes, 0);
      GetStartupInfo(StartupInfo);
      StartupInfo.hStdOutput := hoWrite;
      StartupInfo.hStdError := hoWrite;
      StartupInfo.hStdInput := hiRead;
      StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW + STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
      StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
    //  GetEnvironmentVariable('COMSPEC', ComSpec, sizeof(ComSpec));
    CreateProcess(nil, PChar('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\rtmpdump\rtmpdump.exe ' + cmd2),
                                nil, nil, True,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, nil,
                                PChar(WorkDir), StartupInfo, ProcessInfo);

      CloseHandle(hoWrite);
      CloseHandle(hiRead);
      PipeMode := PIPE_NOWAIT;
      SetNamedPipeHandleState(hoRead, PipeMode , nil, nil);
      while true do
      begin
        Sleep(10);
        GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
        if ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE then Break;
        ReadFile(hoRead, Buffer, MAX_CHUNK, BytesRead, nil);

        if BytesRead > 0 then
        begin
          for i := 0 to BytesRead - 1 do
          TempStr :=  Tempstr + string(char(buffer[i]));
        end else
        begin
          if TempStr <> '' then
          begin
            try
              except
              break;
            end;
            TempStr := '';
          end;
        end;
        if comand <> '' then
        begin
          WriteFile(hiWrite, pchar(Comando)^, length(comando), BytesWritten, nil);
          WriteFile(hiWrite, #13#10, 2, BytesWritten, nil);
          comando := '';
        end;
      end;

      GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
      if ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE then TerminateProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 0);
      CloseHandle(hoRead);
      CloseHandle(hiWrite);
    end;
```

PS: I have tried -> `generateconsolectrlevent`

Comment: I have  already searched before i post .. most of the answers are non delphi or too complicated

Comment: That doesn't mean this is not a duplicate. The fact that you have found it hard to achieve this does not justify us answering the question again. If you have specific problems implementing solutions proposed in the answers to the dupe, then please ask about them.